# IIS website speed in different country

Tags: iis, networking

I have an IIS server in vancouver BC. When I load the website and do a query within the site. I get the results within 2 - 3 seconds. and I am located in New westminster BC. (about 20 KM from the server)

But when someone in Spain loading the same website it takes about 10-20 seconds.

**Assuming the internet speed is the same and the website traffic is the same and the query is the same**,  why the different speed between querying while I am 20 KMs away vs 9000 kms away?

Does distance play a role in data transfer?

OK, Now I get the answer to this question. It leads to another question. What would be the most feasible solution to the problem? Should we implement ARR with two servers in different countries to implement high availability architecture? or is there some way to create a priority highway to minimize the lag on hops?

Comment: Of course it does. Signals travel through space at a certain velocity. Not to mention more distance == more hops through different servers / isps.

Comment: knowing the speed of electricity is 150,000  miles per second. in theory distance should not be a factor shouldn't it?. then it must be the hops that's slowing things down?

Comment: See my answer! Also, data is not simply transferred but also converted from analog to digital and vice-versa at ends! It's not that simple as what you're thinking!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, distance does play a role in data-transfer. The reason for the same can be attributed to transferring data through several countries and several places and also several WAN's,etc--- so more routers needed,more hopping required and so the time required will obviously be longer.

Also, data is not simply transferred but also converted from analog to digital and vice-versa at ends! It's not that simple as what you're thinking!!! Another factors which you can attribute are more traffic in other end,limited bandwidth(slow internet speed),slow system response!

You can check the number of routers in between using `tr`(traceroute) command in windows!

But,I guess the time-factor which you mentioned mustn't be that much---that might be happening because of slow internet speed at the other end. Else, the ratio is hardly of 3-4 times the first case!

Comment: thanks. yes the ratio should not be this big. I'll see what I can find in traceroute

Answer (score 1):

absolutely.

I have no idea what kind of data that is, but according to your performance, I think the data should be fairly big, roughly 10mb or more.

Think the networking as a network of highways. If you want to travel from Vancouver to Calgary, One kind of delay you are facing is the road distance from Vancouver to Calgary, say 2 hrs. Furthermore, if you are driving a suuuuuuuuper long car as long as 100km(whatever, let it be), you have to spent roughly 1 hr more to totally drive there.

All I have mentioned is the ideal case. TCP/IP will retransmit your data if timeout, which means more delay.

distance can be considered as a major factor of data transfer.

so as the bandwidth.